# Trouble with Joining Tables and Obtaining Data in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case, outer-join

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to run my queries. 


I have two tables in an Oracle database. See below.

```
                  table_1
------------------------------------------------------
    SKU    |  MAIN_LOCATION   |   BACKUP_LOCATION
------------------------------------------------------
    111    |     05-AA        |      09-DD
    222    |     02-BB        |      10-JJ
    333    |     07-CC        |      13-LL
    444    |     06-HH        |      19-PP


                  table_2
---------------------------------------------
    SKU    |    QUANTITY    |    LOCATION
---------------------------------------------
    111    |        5       |     05-AA
    111    |        8       |     09-DD
    222    |        2       |     02-BB
    333    |        4       |     07-CC
    444    |        1       |     06-HH
    444    |        11      |     19-PP
    555    |        16      |     21-UU
```

**What I Need**
What I need is a query that displays all of the SKUs on `table_1` (one SKU per row), and their quantities in columns based on their location from `table_2`. If there is no data provided in the backup location, then I just want a null value to be displayed. Example of what I need is provided below.

```
                   QUERY NEEDED
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SKU  |  MAIN_LOC  |   MAIN_LOC_QTY  |   BACKUP_LOC   |   BACKUP_LOC_QTY
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  111  |     05-AA  |       5         |    09-DD       |      8
  222  |     02-BB  |       2         |    10-JJ       |    (null)
  333  |     07-CC  |       4         |    07-CC       |    (null)
  444  |     06-HH  |       1         |    19-PP       |      11
```

**What I've Tried**

I first ran a query to make sure I was able to pull up all of the SKUs that I needed from `table_1`.

```
SELECT   table_1.sku AS SKU,
         table_1.main_location AS MAIN_LOC

FROM     table_1
```

No problem.
I then added `table_2` to the query, without even adding any columns just to make sure I got the same amount of SKU rows as my previous query, which did not work. See below.

```
SELECT   table_1.sku AS SKU,
         table_1.main_location AS MAIN_LOC

FROM     table_1,
         table_2

WHERE    table_1.sku = table_2.sku(+)
```

This is when I started having a problem; if the SKU exists on two lines in `table_2`, then it shows up in two lines in my query like so:

```
  SKU  |  MAIN_LOC
--------------------
  111  |  09-DD
  111  |  09-DD
  222  |  02-BB
  333  |  07-CC
  444  |  06-HH
  444  |  06-HH
```

I need the above to still only display one row per SKU.


Assuming that the above query even worked, I was still trying to obtain quantity information based on locations, like this:

```
SELECT   table_1.sku AS SKU,
         table_1.main_location AS MAIN_LOC,
         CASE
           WHEN table_1.main_location = table_2.location THEN table2.quantity
           ELSE NULL
         END AS MAIN_LOC_QUANTITY,
         table_1.backup_location AS BACKUP_LOC,
         CASE
           WHEN table_1.backup_location = table_2.location THEN table2.quantity
           ELSE NULL
         END AS BACKUP_LOC_QUANTITY

FROM     table_1,
         table_2

WHERE    table_1.sku = table_2.sku(+)
```

The join/outer join `(+)` is the only way I get all of the SKUs I need, but still wind up getting duplicate rows of the same SKU (which is what I don't want).

I have even tried to make a subquery in the `FROM` statement to cut down on some of the SKUs I do not need, like this:

```
SELECT   table_1.sku AS SKU,
         table_1.main_location AS MAIN_LOC,
         CASE
           WHEN table_1.main_location = sub_table.location THEN sub_table.quantity
           ELSE NULL
         END AS MAIN_LOC_QUANTITY,
         table_1.backup_location AS BACKUP_LOC,
         CASE
           WHEN table_1.back_location = sub_table.location THEN sub_table.quantity
           ELSE NULL
         END AS BACKUP_LOC_QUANTITY

FROM     table_1,
         (
          SELECT  *

          FROM    table_2

          WHERE   location NOT LIKE '%[SOME CONDITIONS]%'
         ) sub_table

WHERE    table_1.sku = table_2.sku
```

This yields pretty much the same result as the previous query. It gets rid of some of the stuff I do not need, but does not address the main problem.


I have also added what little I know of joins/outer joins to the where statement in desperation:

```
WHERE    table_1.sku(+) = table_2.sku
```

As well as:

```
WHERE    table_1.sku = table_2.sku(+)
```

But at this point, I think I am just grabbing at straws and I am flooding myself with too much of what I do not know.


**What My Problems Are**
A)I cannot figure out how to get the `MAIN_LOC_QTY` column to display the quantity based on the `Table 2` data.
B)When a SKU from `Table 1` exists on two rows of `Table 2`, then my query produces two rows for one SKU, when I only need one row to exist with all information pertaining to that SKU.


Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**What My Solution Was** (UPDATED 8/2/2014)
For anyone that came across this, my solution was provided by Brian Demilia below. Essentially, my query is as follows;

```
SELECT   table_1.sku,              --This is from table_1
         table_1.main_location,    --This is from table_1
         main_loc.quantity,        --This is from the 1st LEFT JOIN named main_loc
         table_1.backup_location,  --This is from table_1
         backup_loc.quantity       --This is from the 2nd LEFT JOIN named backup_loc

FROM     table_1
           /*LEFT JOIN below is to make table_2 with only the main_location from table_1*/
           LEFT JOIN table_2 main_loc
             ON  table_1.main_location = main_loc.location
             AND table_1.sku = main_loc.sku
           /*LEFT JOIN below is to make table_2 with only the backup_location from table_1*/
           LEFT JOIN table_2 backup_loc
             ON  table_1.backup_location = backup_loc.location
             AND table1.sku = backup_loc.sku
```

I hope the above helps anyone else who encounters this problem. Thanks to all of the responses.

-Anthony

Comment: Bonus points for the what I need what I tried and what my problem is header. Comment for now...you are using pretty old join syntax, and although this works, it is much easier to use ansi-92 syntax. FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.sku = table_2.sku(+) is equiv to from table 1 right join talbe 2 on table_1.sku = table_2.sku. I suspect you want the left join version of this. Still reading the question ;)  Or just read Justin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.sku,
       t1.main_location,
       ml.quantity        as main_qty,
       t1.backup_location,
       bl.quantity        as bkup_qty
  from table_1 t1
  left join table_2 ml
    on t1.sku = ml.sku
   and t1.main_location = ml.location
  left join table_2 bl
    on t1.sku = ml.sku
   and t1.backup_location = bl.location
 order by t1.sku
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddbe9/4/0

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The SQL Fiddle was extremely informative. Thank you!